# Wrapping Antlr 3.5.2 for OSGi

Tags: osgi, antlr, antlr3

Hibernate uses Antlr (3.5.2 works, apparently), and I'm using Hibernate (therefore also Antlr in an OSGi environment).  I've wrapped antlr-complete-3.5.2-SNAPSHOT.jar as an OSGi bundle, but I exported ALL the packages in the bundle.   The question is simple.  I need to know which Java packages in this bundle are private and which are part of the public Antlr API.  For now, I'm exporting everything
under:

```
antlr.*;
org.antlr.*,
org.stringtemplate.v4.*
```

This is probably exporting too much.  Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 0):

In general, when OSGifying non-OSGi JARs, exporting all packages is the best you can do.

Suppose you could restrict the ANTLR exports without breaking Hibernate, this might still break some other ANTLR client that happens to use one of the packages you didn't export.

Vanilla Java simply doesn't support the concept of private packages.